# How can I hide text output when using <<EOF in my bash script?

Tags: bash

I use the Vagrant and self-written scripts to configure it. One of my scripts contains the following code:

```
mysql_secure_installation <<EOF

y
secret
secret
y
y
y
y
EOF
```

Everything works fine, but I want to turn off text output to the `vagrant up` log. Usually I do it via `>/dev/null 2>&1`, but here I don't know how to use this code.

Tell me please how can I solve my problem? Thx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place it after the first EOF

```
command <<EOF > /dev/null 2>&1
blabla
EOF
```

Comment: Thx, i'm already try use `mysql_secure_installation> / dev / null 2> & 1 << EOF` and this solution very well to)